# Asset database query result in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to assert the result of a database query against a account code value in the page I'm working on but I got the account code value against the query itself.

```
    package login;

    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Window;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import login.SQLConnector;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSS;

    public class FirstLogin {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        baseUrl = "";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);           
      }

      @Test
      public void testAddAccount() throws Exception {


        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("form1:usernameLabel")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("form1:usernameLabel")).sendKeys("test1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("form1:passwordLabel")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("form1:passwordLabel")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("form1:btn_login")).click();
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body table.mainTable tbody tr td p.menuItem a"));   
        action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body table.mainTable tbody tr td p.menuItem a"))).build().perform();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Account")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:locationID")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:locationID")).sendKeys("9999");
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:menu1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:menu1")).sendKeys("10000");
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:menuStatus1")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:usageList"))).selectByVisibleText("Pharmacy");
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textareaDescription1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textareaDescription1")).sendKeys("New");
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:addAcctTerminal")).click();
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:statusList"))).selectByVisibleText("Active");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:TermList"))).selectByVisibleText("Point of Sale");
        driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textSN1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textSN1")).sendKeys("22-55-66");
        driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textPin1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:textPin1")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("AddAcctTerminalData:add")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textDailyLimit1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textDailyLimit1")).sendKeys("10000");
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textCreditLimit1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:textCreditLimit1")).sendKeys("10000");
        driver.findElement(By.id("addPOS:button1")).click();
        assertEquals("Account Added Successfully", driver.findElement(By.id("AddAccountSuccess:CorrectMessage")).getText());
        String AddedAccount = "SELECT CODE FROM ACCOUNTS WEHER ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ACCOUNTS";
        String AccountCode = driver.findElement(By.id("AddAccountSuccess:AccountCode")).getText();


        assertEquals(AddedAccount, AccountCode);    
      }

     }
```

I need to verify AddedAccount against AccountCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.1 version, and selenium 3.0.1 java and jar files are same version, when i try to run my script my mozilla opens but the URL is not displaying in the browser

```
package SessionPack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SessionCalss {

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        System.out.println("String"); 

        WebDriver driver;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\New folder\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 

        driver.get("www.gooogle.com");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the line for AddedAccount to this:

```
String AddedAccount = "SELECT CODE FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ACCOUNTS)";
```